# Setting properties from an object over multiple threads

Tags: c#, properties, thread-safety

I will try my best to explain the situation.

```
public class A
{
    Int64 Id { get; set; }
    Decimal Foo { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    Int64 Id { get; set; }
    Decimal Bar { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    Int64 Id { get; set; }
    Decimal? Foo { get; set; }
    Decimal? Bar { get; set; }
}

public class test
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, C> dictionary { get; set; }
    List<A> listA { get; set; } 
    List<B> listB { get; set; }
}
```

listA and listB each contain 5 million objects.

So what I do is, I loop through listA and listB on seperate threads.
I check if the dictionary contains the id, then get the value and set the matching property.

**So my question is, is this threadsafe? If not, what would be the best way to make it threadsafe**

One more thing :

- There are no duplicates in listA and listB. So I only set the property of any object C once.

An example using dummy data:

```
List<A> listA = new List<A> 
{ 
    new A { Id = 1, Foo = 5 },
    new A { Id = 2, Foo = 10 },
    new A { Id = 3, Foo = 100 }
};

List<B> listB = new List<B> 
{ 
    new A { Id = 1, Bar = 3 },
    new A { Id = 2, Bar = 2 },
    new A { Id = 3, Bar = 1 }
};

ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, C> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, C>
{
    Keys = {1, 2, 3},
    Values = { new C { Id = 1 }, new C { Id = 2 }, new C { Id = 3 } }
};
```

Afterwards I the dictionary would have these key/value pairs :

```
Key = 1 , value = object of class C with properties : Id = 1, Foo = 5, Bar = 3,
Key = 1 , value = object of class C with properties : Id = 1, Foo = 10, Bar = 2,
Key = 1 , value = object of class C with properties : Id = 1, Foo = 100, Bar = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are doing in your loops are accessing object C's that are already in the concurrent dictionary, and setting the properties Foo and Bar respectively, then yes, this should be thread safe.

If you are inserting or removing items from the ConcurrentDictionary, that too should be thread safe provided that you are using the ConcurrentDictionary appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx
Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

So you should be able to access it from any number of threads you want.
**BUT there's a catch**

Lets say that your dictionary is empty, both threads check if the object with the target ID exists and then proceed to add a new one if it doesn't, it can happen that both threads try to add the same new item. So, your dictionary must contain the objects already or else you will have to use locks.